# How to record entire screen on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, recording

Is there a way to record entire screen in Windows 10?

Trying to use the Windows game bar to record (see https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/how-to-video-screen-capture-windows-10), I find that it only records the most recent windows clicked on before hitting the game bar hotkey (perhaps I am using the feature incorrectly).

My actual use case is that I have dual monitors: one large, where I want to record several windows to demonstrate something, and a laptop screen, where I have a script I need to read from (so need to capture audio as well). I then edit these videos in the Photos video editor. I want to record the entire screen of the larger monitor. How can I do this in Windows 10?

Comment: Are you opposed to using 3rd party applications for recording like OBS? There are lots of different applications you can download and use for this.

Comment: @TimG. Not opposed. Don't use Windows much so not sure which would be reputable and easiest to use (was also trying to avoid just polling for software recommendations). Would have to be 1) free and 2) preferably open source.

Comment: [OBS is both of those](https://obsproject.com/).  There was a similar question somewhere on this site as well, but I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: You can use the Windows 10 Built-in Screen Recorder or Xbox Game Bar feature. Here you can check third-party screen recording softwares https://recorder.easeus.com/screen-recording-tips/does-windows-10-have-a-screen-recorder.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [recordscreen.io](https://recordscreen.io)

You don't need to install any software, and you can literally learn to use it in just a few seconds or minutes.

Comment: Didn't work: The site spiked my CPU, and when I tried to view the video it was just a single screenshot.

Comment: Worked for me for simple video. Firefox, Win10.

Answer (score 12):

If you have PowerPoint:

- Click *Insert* -> *Screen Recording*

[image]

- Click *Select Recording Area* and draw a rectangle, for example around the entire screen
- Optionally, select whether to record the microphone audio and cursor, and whether that control window should stay pinned
- Click *Record*
- If the window didn't stay pinned, move the cursor to the top of the screen
- Press *Stop*

[image]

- Right-click on the recorded video, which has appeared in the PowerPoint presentation
- Click *Save Media As...* to save a video file

Source: [this article](https://www.softwarehow.com/record-screen-windows/).

Answer (score 1):

I use [ScreenRec](https://screenrec.com/screen-recorder#changelog).

- It is also available for Linux and Mac
- It allows you to select the window to record or screenshot
- I am using the free version

A screenshot of the settings

[image: Settings]

Blurb from website

> Free Screen Recorder
> ScreenRec is a free screen recorder with no watermark that lets you capture your desktop in one click and share instantly.
>
> - Get started in 60 seconds
> - Record computer audio
> - Record your voice
> - Record your webcam
> - No watermarks or time limits
> - Lightweight screen recorder (no lag)
> - Cloud Recording technology

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 has a built-in screen recording feature for **some windows** (not for the entire screen, and not for some apps, e.g. not for Windows Explorer):

Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

Alternatively, press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to open the Game Bar and click on the filled circle.

There are buttons to turn the microphone on/off and stop recording.

The video is stored in `%USERPROFILE%\Videos\Captures\`

Answer (score 0):

1. Google Chrome has some Screen Recording extensions.  If you're running Chrome, navigate to https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/screen?hl=en and see some of the options.
2. There are many third-party Windows screen capture applications like SnagIt or Screen-Cast-O-Matic which cost money.  There may be free ones as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can screen record the entire screen on Windows 10. (From GTX 1050 Ti)

1. Use OBS, it’s free and can record in 4K 60 and has customizable bitrate. However it has trouble recording demanding games. I found that a demanding game was running at 60 FPS while OBS recorded at 1-6 FPS. OBS can also record from multiple monitors.
2. If you have a Nvidia GPU you can download GeForce Experience for free which records at 4K 60 with customizable bitrate. Unlike OBS it will record well even on demanding games and won’t effect performance as much. Although I don’t have a way for it to record multiple monitors. The app has other features like screen record the last 30 seconds and game optimization.